# R grouping by trivial example

Tags: r, group-by

I am discovering `R` and I need to do some "grouping by" functionnality so I tried this

```
test<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(4,4,5,6))
test[,by=list(B)]
```

and I got this

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , by = list(B)) : 
  unused argument (by = list(B))
```

where am I going wrong ?

Comment: What are you looking to do after grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more row convert `data.frame` to `data.table`

```
test<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(4,4,5,6))
test=data.table(test)
test[,by=list(B)]


   A B
1: 1 4
2: 2 4
3: 3 5
4: 4 6
```

Comment: you mean we have to convert a `data.frame` into `data.table why so ?

Comment: `test[,by=list(B)]`, this is `data.table` function not for `data.frame`,  `data.frame` and `data.table` are different data Structure.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look into the packages created by Hadley Wickham, starting with `dplyr` which is a part of the `tidyverse` for data wrangling.  Also here are two simple examples of what you could do after the grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
test<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(4,4,5,6))
test %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarise(counts = n(),
            sum = sum(A))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      B counts   sum
  <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
1     4      2     3
2     5      1     3
3     6      1     4
```

He has written a couple books and has a nice [website](http://tidyverse.org/) that explains the packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to group and sum you can use:

`aggregate(test$A, by=list(test$B), FUN = sum)`